# Append grep match count number on same line

Tags: grep, append

I did this but it appends to a newline instead of the last line

`grep -rc "WORD" /home/user/data >> file`

Answer (score 0):

Removing trailing newline(\n) character and then re-directing the output to file :

```
grep -rc "WORD" /home/user/data | tr -d '\n' >> file
```

Comment: Actually I just need to use printf instead of echo on my previous command, thanks anyway